# Getting elements by a partial id string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the followng code:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].disabled = bDisabled;
}
```

I need to now add some logic to only disable the the inputs that have and Id of the form "bib*" where bib can be any character. Ive seen other questions where this is done with jquery but I cant use jquery just simple javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Be more precise. "bib" can be any character? Do you mean * can be any character? so that bibo matches but bibliography doesn't?

Comment: Can you use CSS style attribute selectors? I imagine document.getElementsByTagName('[id^=bib]'); would work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if(inputs[i].id.indexOf("bib") == 0)
    inputs[i].disabled = bDisabled;
}
```

Comment: Instead of cycling through them all every time... cache the elements in an array so the next cycle will be quicker.

Comment: TJ, that would be good if the code is running more than once, and there are a relatively small number of matching elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
function CheckDynamicValue(partialid, value) {

    var re = new RegExp(partialid, 'g');
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i = 0, el;
    while (el = elems[i++]) {
        if (el.id.match(re)) {
            el.disabled = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but would CSS style attribute selectors?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('[id^=bib]');
```

Comment: for me this always return an HTMLElement collection with no elements, despite having lots of elements starting with "bib" (or whatever I replaced those characters with)