# Get element by part of Name or ID

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is an example of my form (only inputs that I want, but there is many others):

```html
<form name="inputform" action="..." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_qtedje_77" id="id_qtedje_77" value="0">
    <input type="text" id="id_qte_77" name="prestation_detail_fields[77][qte_collecte]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" id="id_rec_77" name="prestation_detail_fields[77][reliquat_conforme]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" id="id_ren_77" name="prestation_detail_fields[77][reliquat_non_conforme]" value="0.00">
    <input type="checkbox" name="prestation_detail_fields[77][dechet_non_present]" value="1">
    
    <!-- another TR -->
    
    <input type="hidden" name="id_qtedje_108" id="id_qtedje_108" value="0">
    <input type="text" id="id_qte_108" name="prestation_detail_fields[108][qte_collecte]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" id="id_rec_108" name="prestation_detail_fields[108][reliquat_conforme]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" id="id_ren_108" name="prestation_detail_fields[108][reliquat_non_conforme]" value="0.00">
    <input type="checkbox" name="prestation_detail_fields[108][dechet_non_present]" value="1">
</form>
```

What I want is to get values of inputs, but as the form is built in PHP, I don't know the line identifier (77, 108).

Is there a way to do something like `getElementByName('id_qtedje_%')` ?

Note: I'm not using any library, and I don't plan to use one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/javascript-getelementbyid-wildcard

Someone asked already...

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Although the answer there is outdated.

Comment: @ Pye: Do you use any library? (jQuery, MooTools, Closure, Prototype...)

Comment: How do you know what you want to get if you don't know the ids? Do you mean you just want to get all of the values?

Comment: `document.querySelector('[id^="id_qte_"]')`?

Comment: Why don't you have a look at this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061760/document-getelementbyid-regex][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061760/document-getelementbyid-regex

Comment: I'm not using any library, and I don't plan to use one.

Comment: This is a very simple solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/998884/892955 - you might want to filter the elements by form first and then input but that's basically it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementById() wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/getelementbyid-wildcard)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your best bet is probably [`document.querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), which you can use any CSS selector with, including an ["attribute starts with" selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) like `input[id^="id_qtedje_"]`. It's [supported on all modern browsers, and also IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="id_qtedje_"]');
```

If you wanted just the first match (rather than a list), you could use `document.querySelector` instead. It returns a reference to the first match in document order, or `null` if nothing matched.

Alternately, you could give the elements a class name, then use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname), but note that while `getElementsByClassName` was supported in old versions of Chrome and Firefox, IE8 doesn't have it, so it's [not as well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname) as the more-useful `querySelectorAll` in the modern era.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("theClassName");
```

If you use any libraries (jQuery, MooTools, Closure, Prototype, etc.), they're likely to have a function you can use to look up elements by just about any CSS selector, filling the gaps in browser support with their own code. For instance, in jQuery, it's the `$` (`jQuery`) function; in MooTools and Prototype, it's `$$`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

```
var listOfElements = $('[name^="id_qtedje_"]')
```

You may also be interested with the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) and [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors

---

Using `querySelectorAll`, you can do

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name^="id_qtedje_"]')
```

---

Alternatively:

Assuming that all elements are `input`s, you may use this:

```
function getElementByNameStart(str) {
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('input')
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if(x[i].indexOf(str)==0) {
            return x[i];
        }
    }
}
```

which can be called as getElementByNameStart("id_qtedje_")

Note that this only returns the *first* element of this type. To return all:

```
function getElementByNameStart(str) {
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName('input')
    var a=[];
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if(x[i].indexOf(str)==0) {
            a.push(x[i])
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

If the elements are of any type, replace "input" with "*" (beware, this may make your code slow)

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer to the question and I don't know why someone voted this down. There isn't really a better way to do it.

Comment: @marksyzm: I think that has to do with my initial (accidental) submit. See the first revision, I hadn't finished typing it yet and I tabbed to the submit button. :S It's no biggie, just a downvote :)

Comment: @marksyzm Because the question someone does not want jQuery.