# Get the div by partial value of id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in my form

```
<div id="s2id_s52dcecf43a846_membership">
<div>
```

I want to find the div by the name "membership" because the other elements of the id are randomly generated.

How to get the div by just getting the partial value of the div id ?

I want to get it via jQuery/Javascript.

Thanks,

FaisalNasir

Comment: Why don't you add `class="membership"` to all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the **id starts with** "membership" and then comes the random part you can use:

```
$('[id^="membership"])
```

You can also use "**contains**" selector, like

```
$('[id*="membership"])
```

If you want to search **by the name**, you can use

```
$('[name=membership]');
```

Keep in mind this might give you more than one element.

You can also check more selectors [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Is there a way to get this via raw javascript, such as document.getElementById combined with a regular expression or something?

Comment: @code-sushi such complex selectors are not available in CSS. Its possible but you need to iterate many elements and will end up with many lines of code.

Comment: Just for the record it can be done using CSS; my question was about raw javascript.  I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874630/get-element-by-part-of-name-or-id#15874766

For CSS, one would do as follows (assuming you are looking for anything with "member" in it)
div[id*='member'] { /* your css goes here */ }

Thanks for pinging me to follow up, though!

Answer (score 1):

*just getting the partial value of the div id*

Just try the `attribute contains selector`,

```
$('[id*="membership"])
```

Or the better way would be add a common `class` to those elements

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to know more about Jquery selectors