# getElementById from concatenated id in twig

Tags: javascript, twig

How do I get an element by id in `javascript`, kinda like this:

```
document.getElementById('assistance').style.display = 'none';
```

If the element id is defined in `twig` like this:

```
<div id="assistance-{{ key }}">
```

Comment: Exactly like that … just with the ID you used twig to generate.

Comment: You should know the key value for that, you could do 'assistance-'+key.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/15874630/5923666

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- You will only have one element with `id` starting with **assistance** and
- You don't know what `id` will be generated

You can use `document.querySelector` with **attribute-starts-with** match

```
document.querySelector('[id^="assistance--"]').style.display = 'none';
```