# Search for element by its specific part of name

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

could someone point me to solution how to find some selector if you know only part of its ID?

As an example, there is a page with input field NAME which ID is :firstname:
So, to found this selector by the common way is Selector("#firstname"). 
But what if I want to found selector which contains string "name" in its ID?

This is a workaround for me. Because on-page there is a selector "#\27 contactName > div > input" 
End because of this character "\27" which is equal to ' sign, testcafe framework cannot found such selector in DOM tree.

I have tried: 
Selector("#\27 contactName > div > input") or Selector("#'contactName > div > input"), but it does not help.

I understand and know that this is not a problem with Testcafe, but with web coders :D. Agree. But still, how to solve it?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874630/get-element-by-part-of-name-or-id

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
$("[id*='name']").val
```

and your jquery as you want

You can also add your tags like.

```
$("input[id*='name']").val
```

or any you like