# Get elements by name that contain part of a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to select all the elements who's name value contains the string "visitors" using Javascript. I cannot add a class in this case.

```
<select name="visitors10">
   <option class="disableDuration4" value="5">5</option>
   <option class="disableDuration5" value="6">6</option>
   <option class="disableDuration6" value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select name="visitors11">
   <option class="disableDuration4" value="5">5</option>
   <option class="disableDuration5" value="6">6</option>
   <option class="disableDuration6" value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select name="visitors12">
   <option class="disableDuration4" value="5">5</option>
   <option class="disableDuration5" value="6">6</option>
   <option class="disableDuration6" value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Duplicate: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874630/get-element-by-part-of-name-or-id)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element by part of Name or ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874630/get-element-by-part-of-name-or-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

```js
let ele = document.querySelectorAll('select[name^=visitors]')

console.log(ele)
```

```html
<select name="visitors10">
   <option class="disableDuration4" value="5">5</option>
   <option class="disableDuration5" value="6">6</option>
   <option class="disableDuration6" value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select name="visitors11">
   <option class="disableDuration4" value="5">5</option>
   <option class="disableDuration5" value="6">6</option>
   <option class="disableDuration6" value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select name="visitors12">
   <option class="disableDuration4" value="5">5</option>
   <option class="disableDuration5" value="6">6</option>
   <option class="disableDuration6" value="7">7</option>
</select>
<select name="xyz"></select>
<select name="visitorsxyz"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.querySelectorAll("select[name^=visitors]")
```