# Get dynamic elements by the middle/End of it's class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to find a group of elements by the end of their class names, it's highly similar to this [Get element by part of Name or ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874630/get-element-by-part-of-name-or-id) however using `document.querySelectorAll([class~=<constant string>])` does not work but `[class=<full class name` including randoms chars (see below) does work.

The elements in question have a class name like. (random string of three chars)-(Some constant String) is it possible to find them by the (some constant string)?

Comment: Please provide either a better description or preferably real failing/succeeding example code. Anyway the OP should be able to find a solution just by reading about e.g. [Attribute selectors syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The correct syntax is `$=` to find a class that ends with a particular string.
2. If you want to use a variable in that selector use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert it.

```js
const constant = '123';
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(`[class$="${constant}"]`);
divs.forEach(div => console.log(div.textContent));
```

```html
<div class="abc-123">Will be selected 1</div>
<div class="def-234">Will not be selected 1</div>
<div class="ghi-123">Will be selected 2</div>
<div class="jkl-234">Will not be selected 2</div>
```

Comment: Does this work with getElementsByClassName as well?

Comment: No. `getElementsByClassName` requires a specific class. You can't test for the end of classes with that.